# Properties of a module for these never changed (or just once at beginning) settings?

Tags: f#

I have the following module, basically, the parameter `yyyyMMdd`, `options`, and `folder` are passed around for a lot of functions to be used. It will only be assigned/changed in the `main` once, or never need to be updated (`folder`, `options`).

How to implement "Property" of an F# module so there is no need to let all these functions have these parameters?

```
module X

let a theDate x options = .... // aDate is used here

let b theDate x folder options = a theDate 30 options //....

let c theDate folder options = b theDate 100 folder options //... other statements omitted. 

let main yyyyMMdd folder options =
    let aDate = .... // convert yyyyMMdd to type DateTime
    ...
    c aDate folder
    ...
```

---

Update: I defined the following type with static memebers for it. Is it F# idiomatic?

```
type Settings() =
    static member val TheDate= DateTime.MaxValue with get, set
    static member val Folder = "" with get, set
    static memeber val Options = ??? with get, set
```

Comment: wrap your logic into a class and pass the necessary data as parameters.

Comment: Is class not preferred in functional programming?

Comment: F# is not pure FP, and classes are good at creating encapsulation boundaries. Don't forget that it runs of top of .NET. I wouldn't be too dogmatic about it. Using `mutable` is even less "preferred". :-) It is also very easy to use them in F#, as `let` bindings will automatically become private. The problem you are bumping into is that `module` in F# is less powerful than in some other languages (for good or bad), it cannot be parametrized by passing arguments into it, it's just like a namespace. Classes can do what you want, and a type can take a parameter.

Comment: I would go with the simpler `__.TheDate` which is basically a read-only property. But see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840948/when-should-i-use-let-member-val-and-member-this

Answer (score 1):

Mutable let bindings can do what you ask for:

```ml
module MyModule =
    let mutable myMutableValue = 42

    let f1 a b = ... // you can use myMutableValue inside
```

Then, to mutate it, do `MyModule.myMutableValue <- xyz`.

Note though that having a global mutable variable in a module is not idiomatic F#. Without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish, though, it's tough to give better advice, but if I were to give it anyway, I'd say you should keep it as a parameter to all these functions (you'll thank yourself later when you don't have race conditions and other mutability related bugs).

Comment: These settings are like the read-only properties in a C# class.

Comment: @ca9163d9 why do you want to be able to mutate it then? To initialize them somewhere else?

Comment: The values of some properties will be unknown until the main function is running. Like the constructor of a class sets some of these properties in c#

Comment: @ca9163d9 Gotcha. I would probably encapsulate these variable settings in a class as an instance property, and instantiate it when you need it. You could also do this with a record if you please.