# F# Records with members vs Classes

Tags: f#

In F# you can define records with member functions, and you can also create classes.

```
type Album = {
    Id: int
    Name: string
    DateReleased: DateTime
    Genre: Genre }
with
    member this.PrintMessage() =
        printf "Hello from %s\n" this.Name
```

so used

```
let first = 
        { Id = 1; 
          Name = "Hello World!"
          Genre = KPop;
          DateReleased = DateTime(1991, 8, 12) }
first.PrintMessage()
```

and with classes it could be something like this.

```
type Album(
     Id: int, 
     Name: string, 
     DateReleased: DateTime, 
     Genre: Genre ) as me =
     do
         me.PrintMessage()
     member this.PrintMessage() =
         printf "Hello %s" Name
```

When it is convenient to use one or the other?
Can Domain Modeling only be done with records?

Can a class be converted to a record and vice versa by some hidden FSharp Casting?

Comment: Answers to these and similar questions can be found throughout https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/

Comment: And here: https://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/

Comment: Thanks @BentTranberg.

Comment: Think you will find some of this interesting also, particularly the slide at around 54:15 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGLxyyTF3OM

Comment: You can use `[<CLIMutable>]` on immutable records in order to use them as entities with databases and such. They will then also have a default constructor.

Answer (score 6):

Domain modeling can be done with both records AND classes. I think when to use one or the other is primarily a matter of preference and environment. Personally I typically do not use classes, however I know some people who use them quite frequently. Classes rely more on mutation and are more performant at a cost of ease of use. Personally I feel as a general guidance that if you are going to write object oriented style then use classes and if you are writing functional style use records. Records pattern match and deconstruct easier. Part of this distinction is cultural, just because you can do a thing in a particular way doesn't mean other people will be able to understand you easily. Code is written to be read, both by yourself and others. When you pick records or classes it communicates intent about the style and usage of those types. Finally I don't know that a class can be converted to a record within F# and if it can I would actually still recommend against it. This is because using records as classes and classes as records clashes with the cultural norms around those constructs. I personally think your example member is fine for both records and classes. I normally like to use modules with the same name for functions associated with a given type because it can make it less confusing when the function happens to consume something other than the record type. However I don't think anyone well mannered would balk at either of your code examples there.

```
type Album(
    Id: int, 
    Name: string, 
    DateReleased: string, 
    Genre: int ) as me =
    let mutable genre = Genre  
    //readonly property
    member val Id = Id
    //autoproperty with get and set
    member val Name = Name with get, set
    member val DateReleased = DateReleased with get, set
    //property with explicit get and set
    member this.Genre 
        with get () = genre
        and set (value) = genre <- value
```

see [When should I use let, member val and member this.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840948/when-should-i-use-let-member-val-and-member-this)

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. I want to have a simple way to introduce my students to the OOP, without the complexity and verbosity of Java, so I've decided on F #. And at the same time, I do not want to explain SQL, or ORM, since it's another teacher's job, so I've decided on LiteDB for persistence. That's where the classes do not fit me. I do not know how to save classes (only attributes and not members) can be saved in LiteDB.
Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for teaching people F#! Secondly I think since you are writing OOP, F# classes are probably a better fit for what you are doing. I'll update my answer to show how to use properties.

Comment: As I understand it this should work with LiteDB because the  `member val Name = Name with get, set` is the same as what LiteDB expects in C#.

Comment: If mutability (the ability to change properties) is not important to you then I think a record would probably be fine.

Comment: Thanks Again. As you can image mutability is important in traditional OOP, so  classes are my choice (of course not for modeling simples Objects). And thanks for the explanation of get, set with members

Answer (score 1):

To complicate matters a bit, it's not only F# record fields vs. CLI properties as data containers. Both are the same under the hood: accessors to immutable F# record fields are implemented as CLI property getters.

If your use case allows it, you may also employ CLI fields, with F# `mutable val` definitions. On the other hand the similar, read-only `val` definition is also exposed by a property getter.

```
type Album =
    // CLI property getter
    val Id : int
    // mutable CLI field
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable Name : string
    // non-primary constructor with sequence construction (before)
    new (id: int, name : string) as me =
         { Id = id } then me.Name <- name
```

There are downsides:

- lack of a primary constructor,
- unwieldiness of the additional constructor expression,
- ensuring default initialization for the field's type, with `DefaultValueAttribute`

And it may be considered unidiomatic.

Comment: This approach looks even less verbose and easy. And i Like simplicity

Comment: I was almost sure that I should use classes, but I think that in each case you should study and adopt the simplest approach. And in that F# wins thanks to its many possibilities. There is a lot to evaluate and prove. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider having a module with the same name as the record type like this:

```
type Album = {
    Id: int
    Name: string
    DateReleased: DateTime
    Genre: Genre
}
module Album =
    let printMessage album =
        printfn "Hello from %s" album.Name

let first = {
    Id = 1
    Name = "Hello World!"
    Genre = KPop
    DateReleased = DateTime(1991, 8, 12)
}
Album.printMessage first
```

Comment: Width this aproach, may I ingerir this record/module from and other record/module?

Comment: Essentially the Album module is a container for all the functions related to Album for the given record. This is how I personally use F#.